# Why RewriteRule in .htaccess does not have effect?

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, configuration

Apache web server is running under Windows 7 professional. Apache version is Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8. mod_rewrite is loaded according to `phpinfo()`. `<VirtualHost>` tag contains `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` directives. Log file set in `RewriteLog` directive is created.

`.htaccess` file in root directory is following:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule ^alice\.html$ bob.html
```

Current directory contains `bob.html` file and it can be opened with localhost URL.

But `alice.html` URL can not be opened, it causes error 404.

Log file for this site contains just normal message about file not found.

Rewrite log file exists but empty.

Which can cause rewrite directives being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have this line in your httpd.conf:

```
AllowOverride All
```

**AllowOverride** controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.

**Testing:** To test whether .htaccess is enabled or not, just put some junk text in it and see if it generated a 500 internal error or not.

Comment: `All`? Why not just the required `FileInfo`?

Comment: @Gumbo: Agreed FileInfo will just be fine, All basically allows all the options like FileInfo, AuthConfig, Limit etc.