# Redirecting a specific dynamic URL to a prettier/simple URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a page via my .htaccess, but it does not seem to be working.

Old page: /dyn/?q=customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1

New page: /customer-references/

Thought it would be as simple as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=customer(?:[\ +]|%20)reference&f=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dyn/$ /1? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But it does not seem to be working. Is it because the original page's dynamic URL?

Additionally, I also tried a straight 301 Redirect in the .htaccess. That didn't seem to work either:

```
redirect 301 /dyn/?q=customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1 /customer-references/
```

And another failed attempt was this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^customer%20reference&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&c=10,10,10,10,10,10&s=1,1,1,1,1,1,1&st=1$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/customer-references/? [R=301,L]
```

Then, I attempted variations on this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=customer%20reference* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/customer-references/ [R=301,L]
```

Do I need to escape out the ampersands or the space (%20)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping of `%` and `&` is not necessary as they are not special characters.

The following works for me. Place in the .htaccess file in the root of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# match/dyn/?q=customer%20reference&f=[ANYTHING]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=customer%20reference&f= [NC]
RewriteRule ^dyn/$ /customer-references/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working. I don't need to reboot apache in order for this to be picked up do I?

Comment: @Keefer Its possible your .htaccess is not enabled. Put some junk in your .htaccess e.g `asdfasdfwerwer` and see if that gives you a 500 error. If yes, then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990378/why-rewriterule-in-htaccess-does-not-have-effect for solution

Comment: .htaccess is definitely enabled and being utilized. I've got several active 301 redirects, some cache control stuff, etc. that's all working fine.

Comment: @Keefer I had a stray `#` in my solution instead of a `$`, fixed above. Let me know if that works

Comment: And just to confirm, yeah, putting some random text in gives a 500.

Comment: yeah, changing that # to a $ did it. Thanks so much.